# Column as content with FOR XML PATH query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have a SQL query to get data from SQL Server 2012:

```
select dbo.TRIM(cfProj.cfProjId) as "cfProjId", 
       dbo.TRIM(cfProj.cfAcro) as "cfAcro",
       (SELECT cfLangCode as "@cfLangCode", cfTrans as "@cfTrans", cfProjTitle.cfTitle 
        FROM dbo.cfProjTitle
        WHERE dbo.cfProjTitle.cfProjId = dbo.cfProj.cfProjId
       FOR XML PATH('cfTitle'), type)  
from cfProj FOR XML PATH('cfProj')
```

This SQL returns data structure like:

```
<cfProj>
  <cfProjId>00001111</cfProjId>
  <cfAcro>222</cfAcro>
  <cfTitle cfLangCode="ru" cfTrans="h">
    <cfTitle>some title here</cfTitle>
  </cfTitle>
</cfProj>
```

But I want get XML structure without second nested "cfTitle" element:

```
<cfProj>
  <cfProjId>00001111</cfProjId>
  <cfAcro>222</cfAcro>
  <cfTitle cfLangCode="ru" cfTrans="h">some title here</cfTitle>
</cfProj>
```

Difference in this line: `<cfTitle cfLangCode="ru" cfTrans="h">some title here</cfTitle>`

Any ideas how I can get desirable result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need multiple cfTitle elements, you can use marc_s solution, but if you do - you can try this:

```
select 
    p.cfProjId, 
    p.cfAcro,
    (
        select
            pt.cfLangCode as [@cfLangCode],
            pt.cfTrans as [@cfTrans],
            pt.cfTitle as [text()]
        from cfProjTitle as pt
        where pt.cfProjId = p.cfProjId
        for xml path('cfTitle'), type
    )
from cfProj as p
for xml path('cfProj')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac7b0/3)</kbd>**